# How Can I Deploy My Bokeh Graphs in an Online Server?

Tags: python, flask, web, deployment, bokeh

I've been trying to deploy some graphics I've made in Bokeh into an online server, where other people could see it also. What can I do to do this? I don't know if I should use Jinja, if I just need to use flask as a framework... I've made a deploy of my index.html, but it was in Jinja, and all my Jinja code were taken as paragraphs.

I've tried 4 servers. When I used flask, my bokeh graphs just don't appear. What should I do?

I already have my graphics ready, and I can see them at a local server, but I have no idea how to put them in an online server. Do I need to deploy the back-end and the front-end separately? Thanks

Comment: Does this [section](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server/deploy.html) in the user guide help you?